# How filter a result?

Tags: php, laravel

I work with MailChimp API. 
I use index method:

```
public function index()
{
    return $this->MailChimp->get("campaigns");
}
```

Get method:

```
public function get($method, $args = array(), $timeout = self::TIMEOUT)
{
    return $this->makeRequest('get', $method, $args, $timeout);
}
```

As a result I get big massive of information:

```
{
"campaigns": [
    {
        "id": "",
        "web_id": ,
        "type": "",
        "create_time": "",
        "archive_url": "",
        "long_archive_url": "",
        "status": "",
        "emails_sent": 0,
        "send_time": "",
        "content_type": "",
        "needs_block_refresh": ,
        ]
    },
```

How filter this array that in result I get only fields as I need (such as `id` and `web_id`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [official guide](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#partial-responses). See the part **Partial responses** and the example:

```
https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?fields=lists.name,lists.id
```

Yo are allowed to use `fields` parameter for all requests. Including **campaigns**.